# Stored procedure visible in EF6 model browser, but can't call it from code

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have added a stored procedure to my SQL Server database, and have updated the EF6 model. I can see the stored procedure in the Function Imports section of the model browser, but I cannot access it in code to call it.

We have another stored procedure imported into the model, and we call that as follows..

```
((MyEntities)ctx).SupportTicketsSearch(searchText)
```

However, Intellisense doesn't show the new stored procedure when I try the same thing, and if I type the name manually, I get a compiler error. The only difference I can see between the two is that the other one returns rows, this one doesn't.

If I look in the generated context .cs file, I can see the other stored procedure in the `#region Function Imports` section, but this one isn't there.

I tried deleting it from both stored procedures and function imports and then reimporting it, but the same happened - it showed up in both places in the model browser, but I can't access it from code.

Note that this does not seem to be a permissions issue, as EF imported the stored procedure and shows it in the model browser. However, to double-check, I tried granting execute permission to `public` in SQL Server and updating the model, but this didn't make any difference.

Anyone any ideas why the stored procedure shows up in the model browser, but doesn't show up in code?

Comment: Could you show the code of your store procedure to replicate this issue on my development enviroment, because i had this problem before and the bug was in my stored procedure

Comment: In advance make sure that when you execute the  stored procedure it returns a table

Comment: @okyam Ah, I wonder if that was the problem. The SP that works did indeed return data, but this new one did not. I deleted some data from a table, but didn't return anything. I wonder if that was the issue. If so, how are you supposed to call a SP that doesn't return any data?

Comment: You can do it with this aproach, db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_DeleteExample @ExampleID ", new SqlParameter("@ExampleID", value)); but i think that the best way is to set an ouput parameter and when you import the SP in EF in the import funtion set the return a collections of scalars.  this will help you to know if the SP works well.

Comment: @okyam I modified the Sp to return a value, and was able to use it from the code, so it looks like this is the answer. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll mark it? If not, I will. I tried the `db.Database` approach, but couldn't see a `Database` property anywhere. What is your `db` variable?

Comment: Great!!, i will post the ansewer.  db variable is the dbcontext.

Comment: Database property in the dbcontext is available with the namespace system.data.entity in entity framework 6 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you stored procedure return a value, so entity framework can create the imported function without any issue and you can see the function in your dbcontext.

Another aproach is to call you SP like this:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_Delete @ID", new SqlParameter("@ID", value));
```

[Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx) property is available in your dbcontext with the namespace systema.data.entity in entityframework 6

Answer (score 0):

make sure your user have permission to execute this stored procedure too.